# CSS / HTML overflow problem on a web page

Tags: html, css, windows, overflow

Current webpage condition image:

[image: Current webpage condition image]

I am a new programmer currently teaching myself HTML / CSS / JavaScript. I am practicing making a webpage and trying to get out of the tutorial swamp by getting my hands dirty.

I've made one webpage I'm happy with and this is my second one. My problem I believe is with my .png image in my html file as when it loads in it loads very large and makes the page overflow by a lot. Even after changing the width and adding a overflow: hidden; it takes away the scroll bars but the page is still messy.

I've tried the overflow: hidden; on the html, body{} and the img tag itself. I will provide my code and photos of the page currently to show you the issue. In the meantime overflow hidden will be turned off.

(There's a photo of the page in the link). Code posted below

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    padding: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

header {
    background-color: purple;
    background-image: url(../imgs/mountains.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Practice2 page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/practice2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="imgs/image1.png" alt="logo" width="200">
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-bar">
                    <li><a href="#">HomePage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="hook">
                <h1>DeadInside</h1>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i wanna apologize im still relatively new to this, what is word press? im using VS code.and also what is Maiusc? thank you for any help!!

Comment: [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/) is a software that let's you build web-sites and helps you for manage them in an easier way thank the websites developed in full html/css/js. It is actually one of the most popular. With Maiusc i meant the key on the Keybaord !!! Ctrl + Maiusc + R is a keyboard shortcut, a sequence of keys that you have to press on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `.wrapper` class, it has `padding:1170px` and that causes the wrapper elem to be way bigger that the body

Try as this

```
.wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can use the padding in all the diorections with the

```
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
```

More about this property on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

Comment: that worked so far!! i set it to 100px just to test and thats small what would you suggest i set it too??

Comment: @KevinMichealProsser That depends on the graphic that you want to have on the page, there is not a default or a correct value :) ! If the answer was helpful think about marking it as the correct one!